# Where can I find modern Mac OS X Cocoa documentation?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have been trying to learn how to program using Cocoa on my Mac OS X computer (Running Mac OS version 10.14.2) using Xcode (Running version 10.1)

The challenge I have been having is finding up to date documentation. Most tutorials I can find are for Xcode version 3.x, which seems to not even apply to my version of Xcode, as they mention files that I don't see and tell me to click buttons that do not exist.

Where can I find up to date documentation for Cocoa programming on Mac OS so I can make GUIs for my programs?

I need documentation/tutorials pertaining to things like editing the main.storyboard file, what all the files Xcode automatically makes mean and do, how I can add buttons and make them do various things, taking user input from the keyboard, and Cocoa in general so that I can start making GUIs for my programs.

Comment: Documentation is built into Xcode (Help > Developer Documentation), however it sounds like you are after tutorials that use more modern versions of Xcode?

Comment: @trojanfoe Indeed I am, do you know of any more tutorial type sources maybe? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I don't know any specifically but these days it will be Swift only and not Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's documentation (and they are far from unique in this) has steadily gone downhill for both macOS and iOS. Fortunately they have kept their old tutorial documentation available in an archive, and even some of their current documentation directly links to it!

You can find the archive at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/. In the area of GUI the tutorials give a description of the model which is still valid, though any screenshots will look old! Read these tutorials in conjunction with the current API docs to check for changes and new widgets that have been added.

Also on Apple's developer site you'll find recordings of WWDC talks, the developer forums, and even old tech notes.

HTH

Comment: Is Apple really "far from unique in this"? Microsoft's documentation on their Windows API has been updated as recently at 2018 and includes both tutorials and references on a modern website.

Comment: @MikeLowrey – did you miss a "/s"? Apple has updated documentation in 2021 but there is more to documentation that the last updated date. I would say the quality & coverage of documentation has gone down across the industry over the years, which in turn has helped in part fuel SO as people can't find good documentation for the APIs, languages, compilers, et al, they are trying to use. Good luck with your studies and keep an inquiring mind, and as one who's been in CS for a while apologies from all of us for the useless documentation you are bound to bump into :-(

Comment: I did miss an 's', guess you can't edit a comment on SO after 5min :(. But yeah, you're right, I misread your comment. Good documentation does not equal recently written documentation. I guess I just tend to associate an older-looking website with older documentation, and therefore less-likely-to-be-accurate documentation. A lack of documentation or good tutorials has definitely been the bane of my time as a programmer. The amount of time you spend just trying to piece together how to work with other people's tech is insane.

Answer (score 1):

iOS has overtaken the Mac in popularity among developers. Apple focuses on iOS in their documentation. People writing articles and tutorials focus on iOS too, leaving out Mac developers. This situation makes it difficult for people who want to learn Mac development.

The best source of Mac tutorials right now is [Ray Wenderlich's site](https://www.raywenderlich.com), but they stopped making Mac tutorials. There's also a [Hacking with macOS book](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/store/hacking-with-macos) that teaches Mac development. I also wrote a couple of Mac articles that might help you: [Make a Simple Mac App in Swift](https://swiftdevjournal.com/make-a-simple-mac-app-in-swift/) and [Creating a Document-Based Mac Application Using Swift and Storyboards](https://meandmark.com/blog/2017/08/creating-a-document-based-mac-application-using-swift-and-storyboards/).

Answer (score 0):

2023 Answer:

I've found some good documentation for macOS here at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/.

You can switch between Swift and Objective C if you wish